# JavaFX handlers not triggered

Tags: java, javafx

I've written the following code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class App extends Application {

    private ListView<String> listView;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        List<String> friendList = new ArrayList<String>();
        friendList.add("Alice");
        friendList.add("Bob");

        listView = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(friendList));
        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> p) {
                ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String t, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(t, empty);
                        if (t != null) {
                            Label usernameLabel = new Label(t);
                            usernameLabel.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 12));

                            Button callButton = new Button("Call");
                            callButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("action")); // not working
                            callButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e -> System.out.println("entered"));
                            callButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> System.out.println("clicked")); // not working

                            HBox usernameBox = new HBox(5);
                            usernameBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                            usernameBox.getChildren().addAll(usernameLabel);

                            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
                            borderPane.setLeft(usernameBox);
                            borderPane.setRight(callButton);

                            VBox vbox = new VBox(3);
                            vbox.getChildren().addAll(borderPane);
                            setGraphic(vbox);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(new Scene(listView));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

If you look at the callButton, you see that it gets three different handlers. However, only the MOUSE_ENTERED event handler is really triggered. The other ones are completely ignored. What can be the problem?

**EDIT**: Added and removed some code, in order to make it runnable.

Comment: Can you update your question with working example?

Comment: Just updated the post. Now it should run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35864) in JavaFX 8, which is fixed in the latest ea release (1.8.0_20).

As a workaround, create the controls once and register handlers with them, then just update their state in the updateItem(...) method:

```
    listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> p) {
            Label usernameLabel = new Label();
            usernameLabel.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
            Button callButton = new Button("Call");

            HBox usernameBox = new HBox(5);
            usernameBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            usernameBox.getChildren().addAll(usernameLabel);

            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
            borderPane.setLeft(usernameBox);
            borderPane.setRight(callButton);

            VBox vbox = new VBox(3);
            vbox.getChildren().addAll(borderPane);

            ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String t, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(t, empty);
                    if (t != null) {
                        usernameLabel.setText(t);
                        setGraphic(vbox);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null); // you will have weird bugs without this: don't omit it
                    }
                }
            };

            callButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("action: "+cell.getItem())); 
            callButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e -> System.out.println("entered "+ cell.getItem()));
            callButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> System.out.println("clicked "+ cell.getItem())); 

            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Note that this "workaround" is really the preferred approach anyway, and the one that was intended by the designers of the "virtualized" controls like `ListView`, `TableView`, etc. The point is that `updateItem(...)` is potentially called very frequently by the application, whereas cells are created very rarely. By creating new controls in the `updateItem(...)` method you potentially introduce performance issues. Create them once for the cell, and then just configure them in `updateItem(...)`. Note also how I just registered the event handlers once, and had the handlers refer to `cell.getItem()` to see which item is currently represented by the cell.

One last thing: you have a bug in your code (which I fixed). Since cells can be reused, including for the case where a cell displaying an item is reused for an empty cell, it's important that you always handle the case where the item is null (typically by setting text and/or graphic to null).

Comment: Thank you for your post, it works now. And thank you for doing even more than I've asked for ;)

Answer (score 2):

Could you add the code of `getIconAndResizeTo16( String s )`. I guess the node you return there consumes mouse clicks.

Here is a runnable example that demonstrates the issue. It is just a guess though.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Button callButton = new Button("", getIconAndResizeTo16("Phone"));
        callButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("clicked1")); // not working
        callButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e -> System.out.println("entered"));
        callButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> System.out.println("clicked"));  // not working

        Button chatButton = new Button("", getIconAndResizeTo16("Chat") );
        chatButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("clicked2")); // not working

        HBox callIconBox = new HBox(3);
        callIconBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        callIconBox.getChildren().addAll(callButton, chatButton);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(callIconBox));
        stage.show();
    }

    private Node getIconAndResizeTo16(String s) {
        Label l = new Label("Consumes " + s + " Events");
        l.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> { e.consume(); });
        l.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> { e.consume(); });
        return l;
    }
}
```